# Published-Draft articles are not searchable

Tags: search

I am using Drupal 8.3.x and Search API 8.x-1.5.

I am new to Drupal and Search API. I have a clarification on Search functionality.

I have created a article where Title and Body fields are indexed. I have published the article.

When I search for the keyword of `Title` or `Body`, article found in search results.

After that I modified the article and saved as draft.

When I am trying search the article with modified text. The article is not returning in the search results.

Can someone please let me know, if this a known issue with the search or it is the expected behaviour? If yes, any specific reason for implementing like this?

Answer (score 1):

> is this a known issue with the search or it is the expected behaviour?

It’s very much the expected behaviour

> If yes, any specific reason for implementing like this?

Yes. Only published content should be visible, unpublished content should not. That’s the whole point of the distinction between the two states.

If unpublished content appeared in search results (without manual intervention if there was an edge-case requirement  to do so), that would be a major bug.

Comment: Hi Clive Thank you very much for the comment. But if I create a new article and save as draft. this new article is searchable even this article is unpublished.  But, only when edited published article is not appearing in search results.